# I'm trying to install eclipse egit but there's this error saying

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Eclipse EGit 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r)
  Missing requirement: Eclipse EGit 2.2.0.201212191850-r (org.eclipse.egit.feature.group 2.2.0.201212191850-r) requires 'org.eclipse.core.runtime [3.7.0,4.0.0)' but it could not be found

My eclipse version is Helios. 
and also there's this list that I dont get.

Eclipse EGit

Eclipse EGit - Source

Eclipse JGit

Eclipse JGit - Source

Eclipse JGit Command Line Interface

Eclipse JGit Command Line Interface - Source

Eclipse Mylyn

Eclipse Plug-in Import Support

How do I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Iam not sure but I think Git support is already available by default in Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know about that. But if you go to your eclipse on the navigator panel and import something, the Git folder must be there. Mine doesn't have one. It must be there, right? it only has the following: General, Android, C/C++, CVS, Run/Debug, Tasks, Team and XML.

Answer (score 17):

If you cannot upgrade to newer eclipse, because of corporate environment for instance,
you can install older EGit version, the upgrade is not revolutionary.
Looks like you are installing from eclipse marketplace. 

Try installing through "Help->Install New Software.."
use "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-2.1" in update site. it will give you older version of egit that is compatible with Helios.

**Make sure to uncheck "Egit plug-in Import Support"** - it is not compatible with Helios

About the other items in list you could easily google about Jgit and Egit relationship and about mylyn and its features

Hope this helps

Comment: great. also the mylyn gave me some errors so i unchecked that one, too

Comment: Missing requirement: EGit Mylyn 2.1.0.201209190230-r (org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group 2.1.0.201209190230-r) requires 'org.eclipse.mylyn.team_feature.feature.group 3.5.0' but it could not be found

Comment: I have tried this and I get: requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse [1.0.0.20110607-2117]' but it could not be found. I looked and I have m2e version 1.0.0.20110607-2117 installed. Not sure how to continue troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 6):

[Egit 2.2 doesn't support Helios](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/2.2#Installation) anymore. Either you stay at Egit 2.1 or you upgrade your Eclipse installation to Juno (which can be done without reinstallation).